# MySQL: Counting items in many joined tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table 'Events' and several joint tables as follows:

Events
+ tags
+ images
+ videos

I would like to be able to form a query, where I can count items in joint tables, if there are some. So I have something like:

```
 SELECT t.*, COUNT(distinct t1.id) visible_tags, COUNT(distinct t2.id) 
        invisible_tags, ..., COUNT(distince tn.id) approved_videos
 FROM events t
 LEFT JOIN tags t1 ON ...
 LEFT JOIN tags t2 ON ...
 LEFT JOIN tags t3 ON ...
 ...
 LEFT JOIN videos tn ON ...
```

The problem is that the query even with all the indexes takes quite a long time. Is there a way how to form it differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with what @sanmai said about 'Explain Select' you can also join subqueries.

```
SELECT t.*, t1_count, t2_count
FROM events t
LEFT JOIN (select count(distinct id) as t1_count from tags) as t1
LEFT JOIN (select count(distinct id) as t2_count from tags) as t2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If a query takes a long time chances are the problem is not in the query.

What indexes are used in this query? Please show use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`